# Issue when converting JSON files to NDJSON with jq not sure how to fix this

Tags: bash, jq

I tried to convert a large number of JSON files in the same directory into NDJSON in order to load them into an analytics tool.

I used jq in order to convert them into one file using the command below.

```
for file in *; do cat $file |jq -c '.[]' >> testNDJSON.json; done
```

The original JSON structure is following

```
{"user_id":"user_id_value",
   "user_properties": {
     "key": "value",
     "key": "value",
     "key": "value"
    }
}
```

Using my command data is written into a file but in the format

```
user_id_value, {"key": "value", "key": "value", "key": "value"}
```

So essentially both user id and user_properties are losing keys + the outer JSON brackets. I'm not sure how to fix this in jq

What I would like to get is the same JSON structure I had line by line in the same file. I don't understand why my command above drops the utmost keys and brackets from JSON.

```
{"user_id":"user_id_value", "user_properties": { "key": "value", "key": "value", "key": "value"} }
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Your command seems to work well. It outputs correctly:

```{"user_id":"user_id_value","user_properties":{"key":"value"}}
{"user_id":"user_id_value","user_properties":{"key":"value"}}
{"user_id":"user_id_value","user_properties":{"key":"value"}}
```

Comment: Let me just check if there is something funny in the original file as that is what I would expect but not what I'm getting

Comment: With valid JSON: I suggest to remove `-c`. Your JSON is not valid with its trailing `,`.

Comment: Ok maybe there is something in my environment causing this. Removing -c just resulted output not to be NDJSON its still dropping they keys and input is valid JSON

Comment: Why not just `jq -c '' * > file`? Why do you expand each object?

Answer (score 0):

This question will be closed. My code above is correct. I had environment configuration in my bash which caused the errors I had.

I'd like to thank @Cyrus and @Antoine Pietri for helpful comments. Learned more about jq tool with this.